# How to explain the concept of "Groups" in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Jetpack Compose by this article http://intelligiblebabble.com/compose-from-first-principles/ , which explain the principle of Compose in a very comprehensible way. However i'm stuck in the conception of "Groups" which handle the cache misalignment when the structure of ui tree changes. It's really hard for me to understand what actually the Groups did. Begging for any comprehensible explanation, thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

First, a group is an internal runtime concept that you really don't need to understand to use compose. That said, a group, from the runtime's perspective is a group of nodes (or other state information) that are composed together. They enter, leave, and move around together.

This can most easily be seen with a function; a function implies a group. Consider the following function:

```
@Composable
fun MyText() {
  Text("one")
  Text("two")
  Text("three")
}
```

This function generates three layout nodes, one for each block of text, but the layout nodes enter, leave, and move together as a group. Either they all are are emitted or none of them are.

Now consider the following,

```
@Composable
fun MyTexts(a: Boolean, b: Boolean, c: Boolean) {
  Column {
    if (a) {
      MyText()
    }
    if (b) {
      MyText()
    }
    if (c) {
      MyText()
    }
  }
}
```

You can see here that the text nodes are emitted conditionally on `a`, `b` and `c`. As the values change all three of the implied nodes are added or removed together. The `Column` node, however, doesn't know anything about the group, it just get told that the nodes are added and removed, there isn't a node that represents the three nodes together in the tree. What tracks that the three nodes from `MyText` are insert and deleted together is the group maintained internally by the runtime.

Now consider the case where the parameter are initially `true` and then later `b` becomes `false` the group makes it easy for the runtime to determine that nodes 3, 4 and 5 need to be removed from the `Column` node without having to know what `MyText` did to produce them. Later, if `b` becomes `true` again, it is easy to determine that three nodes need to be inserted at index 3 (after the three nodes inserted because `a` is `true`).

Comment: So what the structure of the cache storing these nodes would look like? Is this similar to the one in HashMap?

Comment: The data structure used is a gap buffer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer). The groups are stored as elements in the array along with a parallel array to store the remembered state (memo state in the article).

Comment: A hash map is used when a difference is detected.  When a group with a  key is emitted that was the same as last time, the rest of the sibling group keys are collected into a hash table to allow finding if the emitted key was emitted in a different order.